# In scala, is there an alternative to using the :: to append to front or end of a list?

Tags: scala

If a have a `val x = List(2,3,5,8)` and I want to append element 4 to the list, `x::a` or `a::x` work as expected. But is there an alternative to this notation?

Comment: What would make an alternative notation better than `::`? In other words, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `x::a` works? I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, we have:

```
val x = List(2,3,5,8)
val a = 4
```

and you wish to append (in immutable terms) `a` to `x`.

`a::x` works but will return a list with `4` *prepended*, so not what you asked for. `x::a` will not work at all because, well, you can't really prepend a list to an integer.

What you can do, for example, is use the `:+` method:

```
x :+ a  // Returns List(2, 3, 5, 8, 4)
```

Notice however that appending to a `List` requires linear time and may therefore be a bad idea, depending on your particular application. Consider using a different data structure if the performance of this operation is important. More information [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).